# How to install Ecofont on various operating systems?

Tags: installation, fonts

For example, on

- Ubuntu 10.04/11.04
- Debian 6
- Windows XP/7

How can I install [Ecofont](http://www.ecofont.com/) on these operating systems?

Comment: Did you try, you know... right-clicking?

Comment: wat did you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you took a bit to read what it says in the FAQ and the website, you'll find out that there is:

#### Ecofont Software – a printing tool

This is [only available for Windows](http://www.ecofont.com/en/help/ecofont/faq/0001/0018.html) (and therefore not for any Linux or Mac OS X).

Installation is quite simple: Place the EcofontSetup.zip archive in a temporary folder on your local harddisk and unzip the content to an installation directory. Then, run the installer.

#### The Ecofont "Font", just a font file

The Ecofont Vera Sans Regular font is a normal TTF font, which you can [download here](http://www.ecofont.com/assets/files/ecofont_vera_sans_regular.ttf). Installation depends on the OS, and simple research should give you the necessary instructions on how to do that.

- **Ubuntu:** Double click the TTF font and click "Install Font". Or copy it to `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`.
- **Debian:** Since Ubuntu is based on Debian, just put it into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype`. Might be necessary to run `sudo fc-cache -f -v` after that. See the [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Fonts) for more.